# Why am I getting this mysqlclient.lib error?

Tags: mysql, c, database

I'm trying to get everything ready so I can make a database from a C program using mySql. I downloaded the C connector and I have been fixing errors for quite some time trying to run this simple program :

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

//Print the libmysqlclient library version
printf("The MySQL client version is : %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());
return 0;

}
```

At this point,
I'm getting these errors: [image]
Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure without specifically knowing how your compiler and linker are being invoked, but it appears to be a linking problem.

The error is from `ld`, which is the (compile-time) linker, so my guess is that you didn't specify the MySQL library (or possibly some other library that it needs).  The compiler could build the module, but the linker can't link the references to the appropriate library.

It looks like you're using some IDE.  There should be an option somewhere to add to the compiler's (or linker's) command line.  You'd want to append (to the end) something like `-lmysql` or `` `mysql_config --cflags --libs` ``.  The latter uses the `mysql_config` script (which should be available if you have MySQL installed) for the appropriate system-dependent C flags and library flags.  The former just assumes that you have some library called `libmysql`.